# Check gatling test response body with a json feeder

Tags: java, gatling

I'm trying to check the body responses of a service call in a Gatling test. However, I want to have a JSON file to check the expected responses. To do so, I'm using a Feeder and trying to evaluate the actual response with values get from the Feeder. Here is what I have:

data.json:

```
[
  {"out": "pong"}
]
```

SmallTest.java:

```
public class SmallTest extends Simulation {

    public SmallTest() {

        final HttpProtocolBuilder httpProtocol = http
                .baseUrl("https://example.com");

        final FeederBuilder<Object> feeder = jsonFile("data.json");

        final ChainBuilder call = exec(http("Api Response")
                .post("/ping")
                .check(status().is(200))
                .check(jsonPath("$.result").is("${out}")));

        final ScenarioBuilder scenario = scenario("Response Test")
                .feed(feeder)
                .exec(call);

        setUp(scenario
                .injectOpen(atOnceUsers(1))
        ).protocols(httpProtocol);
    }

}
```

The `${out}` statement doesn't work. I get an error saying:

> jsonPath($.result).find.is(${out}), but
> actually found pong

The result of calling http://example.com/ping is the following json response:

```
{
   "result": "pong"
}
```

Side note:

I tried to use `.check(substring("${out}").exists())` and it worked. But this is not what I want. It seems that the `${out}` doesn't work inside a `is()` statement

Comment: When you say "The ${out} statement doesn't work.", what *specifically* happens? Error message? Unexpected value? Something else?

Comment: @Jorn I'm getting a "jsonPath($.result).find.is(${out}), but actually found pong" (added to the original post)

Comment: If I use a ".check(substring("${out}").exists())" then it works. But this is not what I want. So it seems that the "${out}" doesn't work in a "is()" statement

Answer (score 1):

What I was doing wrong was to call the `is()` function and not the `isEL()` instead.

This is because of how the 2 functions work. Check the code and documentation to know more about it.

So the change needed to make my previous code work is to change `is("${out}")` to `isEL("${out}")`